# NTPD Service Won't Start on System Boot

Tags: linux, ntp

Even though ntpd has been enabled, it won't start on system boot. I can issue a "systemctl start ntpd" command that will successfully bring up ntpd, but after reboot ntpd.service goes to inactive (dead). The unit file and ntpd.conf file matches working servers on the same distro version, RHEL 7.5. Selinux has also been disabled. Any ideas?

Systemd unit files:

```
# systemctl status ntpd
● ntpd.service - Network Time Service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/ntpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

# cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/ntpd.service
[Unit]
Description=Network Time Service
After=syslog.target ntpdate.service sntp.service

[Service]
Type=forking
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/ntpd
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/ntpd -u ntp:ntp $OPTIONS
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

# cat /etc/sysconfig/ntpd
# Command line options for ntpd
OPTIONS="-g"
```

ntp.conf file:

```
# cat /etc/ntp.conf 
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/drift
server 10.227.204.142   # added by /sbin/dhclient-script
server 10.235.48.111   # added by /sbin/dhclient-script
server 10.60.248.183   # added by /sbin/dhclient-script
```

Comment: It you've done systemd setup not sure you need this, but maybe `systemctl enable ntpd` ?

Comment: check the logs with " sudo journalctl -u ntpd "

Comment: # systemctl enable ntpd && reboot
# sudo journalctl -u ntpd 
-- No entries --

Answer (score 0):

chronyd.service needs to be disabled in order for ntpd.service to start at system boot